# tsql join with dateparts in subqueries

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have two queries with subqueries for dateparts which I like to join.

```
SELECT  DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring,
    MAX(CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsViewed
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
        FROM FlurryCouponViewed
    ) sub
where couponID=249
GROUP BY DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring

SELECT  DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring,
    MAX(CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsRedeemed
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
        FROM FlurryCouponRedeemed
    ) sub

where couponID=249
GROUP BY DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring
```

The output is of the two queries is:

```
DateMonth   DateYear    Datestring NoOfCouponsViewed
----------- ----------- ---------- -----------------
2           2012        Feb 2012   5
3           2012        Mar 2012   12
4           2012        Apr 2012   25
5           2012        May 2012   25



DateMonth   DateYear    Datestring NoOfCouponsRedeemed
----------- ----------- ---------- -------------------
2           2012        Feb 2012   3
3           2012        Mar 2012   4
4           2012        Apr 2012   5
5           2012        May 2012   11
```

What I like to achive is two have one joined query giving me:

```
DateMonth   DateYear    Datestring NoOfCouponsViewed NoOfCouponsRedeemed
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------------- -------------------
2           2012        Feb 2012   5                 3
3           2012        Mar 2012   12                4
4           2012        Apr 2012   25                5
5           2012        May 2012   25                11
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Just as you do in your queries already, you can use a query as a table.  Well, you can do that for many layers (though it can get hard to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a inner join between the two queries and it should work:

```
SELECT  sub.DateMonth, sub.DateYear, sub.Datestring,
    MAX(sub.CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsViewed,
    MAX(sub2.CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsViewed
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
        FROM FlurryCouponViewed
    ) sub
INNER JOIN
    (   SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
        FROM FlurryCouponRedeemed
    ) sub2 on sub.DateMonth = sub2.DateMonth and sub.DateYear = sub2.DateYear and sub.Datestring = sub2.Datestring
where sub.couponID=249 and sub2.couponID=249
GROUP BY sub.DateMonth, sub.DateYear, sub.Datestring
```

Answer (score 1):

or a `UNION`:

```
    SELECT u.DateMonth, u.DateYear, u.Datestring, MAX(u.NoOfCouponsViewed), MAX(u.NoOfCouponsRedeemed)
    FROM (
        SELECT  DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring,
            MAX(CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsViewed, 0 AS NoOfCouponsRedeemed
        FROM    (
            SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
            CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
            FROM FlurryCouponViewed
            ) sub
        where couponID=249
        GROUP BY DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring
   UNION 
        SELECT  DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring, 0 AS NoOfCouponsViewed,
            MAX(CouponTotalCount) NoOfCouponsRedeemed
        FROM    (
            SELECT  *, DATEPART(MONTH, DateInsert) DateMonth, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInsert) DateYear, 
            CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), DateInsert, 120) Datestring
            FROM FlurryCouponRedeemed
            ) sub

        where couponID=249
        GROUP BY DateMonth, DateYear, Datestring
    ) u
GROUP BY u.DateMonth, u.DateYear, u.Datestring
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UNION` rather than `JOIN`

```
SELECT  MonthInserted, 
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Datestring), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, MonthInserted) AS DateString
        MAX(Viewed) NoOfCouponsViewed,
        MAX(Redeemed) NoOfCouponsRedeemed
FROM    (   SELECT  CouponID, 
                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateInsert)) [MonthInserted], 
                    CouponTotalCount AS Viewed, 
                    0 AS Redeemed
            FROM    FlurryCouponViewed
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CouponID, 
                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateInsert)), 
                    0, 
                    CouponTotalCount
            FROM    FlurryCouponRedeemed
        ) sub
WHERE   couponID = 249
GROUP BY MonthInserted
```

I think a `UNION` would perform better than the `JOIN` in the accepted answer as the `MAX` implies that there are multiple rows per month, and since month is the only common field so it will end up cross joining queries (i.e. if there are 1000 coupons viewed in june 2012 and 500 are redeemed the cross join means you would be selecting the max from 50,000 rows instead of 1500). I am not certain of the schema and logic so this may not be possible, but if there are dates in FlurryCouponRedeemed that are not in FlurryCouponViewed then these will not show.

I also like to keep dates as dates for as long as possible to help the optimiser do it's job, this is why I've replaced `DATEPART(YEAR...` & `DATEPART(MONTH...` AND `CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DateInsert...` with `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateInsert))`